# Looping through string to find space in MIPs

Tags: loops, mips

I'm trying to find a space in a string, I'm getting into the loop but getting stuck. Here's what I have, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. For the space label I did: space:  .asciiz " " and in the name label is a first and last name separated by one space which the user gives.

```
li $t0, 0
la $t0, name

la $t1, space

# loop to find space
loop2:

    lb $a0, 0($t0)
    #comparing char to space
    beq $a0, $t1, exit
    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    j loop2

exit:
```

Comment: There's no need for the `space` string. Just do `beq $a0, ' ', exit`. Or if the assembler doesn't accept that, `li $t2, ' '` before the loop, and then `beq $a0, $t2, exit` inside the loop.

Comment: `beq` compares register values, not pointed-to strings.  Like Michael said, `li $t1, ' '` to put  the space *ASCII character* in a register, not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: $t1 is currently storing an address, you'll have to load the memory from it using `lb $t2, 0($t1)` or something similar

Also, try using an IDE like MARS to help debug your code

Comment: I am using mars but I deleted the increment and its still doing the same thing